# How to compare two values of a column if the values in another column in the same rows match

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I got a dataframe and i want to see the perentage of a win (0 = lose; 1 = win) for the team with the higher amount of wardskilled.

```
  matchid   team    win     wardskilled
0   10        1     0.0        8.0
1   10        2     1.0       10.0
2   11        1     0.0        8.0
3   11        2     1.0        8.0
4   12        1     0.0        2.0
5   12        2     1.0        5.0
6   13        1     0.0        5.0
7   13        2     1.0        5.0
8   14        1     0.0        1.0
9   14        2     1.0        1.0
10  15        1     1.0        3.0
11  15        2     0.0        1.0
..  ..        ..     ..         ..
..  ..        ..     ..         ..
..  ..        ..     ..         ..
```

since im a newby to python i have absolutly no idea how to start

i would love to create something like:

```
       Teams with more wardskilled       Teams with less wardskilled

win              %                                   %

lose             %                                   %
```

i would appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `rank`

If all `'matchid'` have 2 teams, you can use this to determine if the team has a higher, lower or tied `'wardskilled'`. Group by this and calculate the average win.

```
s = df.groupby('matchid').wardskilled.rank().map({1: 'Less', 1.5: 'Tied', 2: 'More'})
df.groupby(s).win.mean()

#wardskilled
#More    1.0
#Less    0.0
#Tied    0.5
#Name: win, dtype: float64
```

Having the two columns is redundant, but if you must:

---

```
res = df.groupby(s).win.mean().to_frame('win_per')
res['loss_per'] = 1-res['win_per']

#             win_per  loss_per
#wardskilled                   
#More             1.0       0.0
#Less             0.0       1.0
#Tied             0.5       0.5
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, you right it's redundant to have the second column.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to compare a team's `wardskilled` with the mean of the two teams:

```
means = df.groupby('matchid') .wardskilled.transform('mean')
df['more_skilled'] = np.sign(df.wardskilled.sub(means))

(df.groupby('win')
   .more_skilled
   .value_counts(normalize=True)
   .unstack('more_skilled', fill_value=0)
)
```

Output

```
more_skilled  -1.0   0.0   1.0
win                           
0.0            0.5   0.5   0.0
1.0            0.0   0.5   0.5
```

Comment: what does the row more_skilled mean? -1 = less , 0 = tie, 1 = more ?

Comment: Yes, `1` means that the difference `df.wardskilled.sub(means)` is positive, so the team is more skilled.